# Bitcoin transaction with 0.0001 BTC fee not getting confirmed?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, confirmations, unconfirmed-transactions

I sent the following transaction a few hours ago with Bitcoin-QT:
https://blockchain.info/tx/b5682b48484a8752be62c6b4036eaf8a8f005d9ea75cbff434476b7506a9e3a2

And the transaction still has not been confirmed. I attached 0.0001 BTC transaction fee.

Did I lose the money? Can I do something to speed up the confirmation of the transaction?

Comment: looks to me like it says your transaction will take up to 26 hours and that your transaction fee was low

Comment: @MarkS. Is it possible to double spend it with an added fee? I'm using bitcoin-qt on mac.

Comment: I don't think any standard wallet will let you double-spend... you would have to hack the transaction yourself.  And even then it probably wouldn't work unless you mined the block yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a time limit for transmission by most clients. I think Bitcoin-qt used 3 days. After that you can spend it again